# XSLT: Replace element/node without original node's text

Tags: xml, xslt

I'm having a play around with XSLT for a project and just trying to get head around using some of the XSLT functions to get a desired output and ran into a small problem which I am trying to solve. I've seen various posts on replacement but none so far which addresses this seemingly simple issue.

Given this XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<catalog>
  <cd>
    <title>Empire Burlesque</title>
    <artist>Bob Dylan</artist>
    <country><font size='8pt' name='Verdana' color='navy'/>USA</country>
    <company>Columbia</company>
    <price>10.90</price>
    <year>1985</year>
  </cd>
</catalog>
```

I am trying to get the expected output (without USA):

```
<div>
    <b>Empire Burlesque</b>
    <p>
        <i>
            <a href="wwww.google.com.au">GOOGLE </a>
        </i>
    </p>
</div>
```

But instead I am getting the below with the additional text "USA".

```
<div>
    <b>Empire Burlesque</b>
    <p>
        <i>
            <a href="wwww.google.com.au">GOOGLE </a>
        </i>USA
    </p>
</div>
```

This is the XSLT I wrote

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:template match="/">
  <html>
  <body>
  <h2>My CD Collection</h2>  
  <xsl:apply-templates/>  
  </body>
  </html>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="cd">
  <div>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="title"/>  
   <xsl:apply-templates select="country"/>
  </div>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="country">
<p>
<xsl:call-template name="replacement">
<xsl:with-param name="txt" select="."/>
</xsl:call-template>

<xsl:apply-templates/>
</p>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="replacement">
<i><a href="wwww.google.com.au">GOOGLE </a> </i>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="title">
  <b><xsl:value-of select="."/></b>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Could someone please give me some pointers on how to get the desired output without the USA text of the country element coming across?

Cheers,

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3914233/skip-over-nodes-with-xslt

Comment: I have rolled your question back to what it was when I answered it. Please start a new question and explain your new issue/s there. If you're getting errors, make sure to quote the error messages too.

Comment: My apologies Michael, it seems we were making changes at the same time. The initial post was a slightly simplified version of my the problem I am trying to solve. I will create a new post as requested, thanks Michael!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your template matching `country` includes an instruction to:

```
<xsl:apply-templates/>
```

This applies templates to all child nodes of `country` - including the text node `"USA"`. You have no templates matching `text()`, so this is processed by the [built-in template rule](https://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xslt-19991116#built-in-rule) that copies text to the output.

If you don't want this to happen, then remove the `xsl:apply-templates` instruction (or add a template to handle the text node/s in a different manner).

Comment: For some reason I can't add this through editing as I seem to be locked out. What I was going to add to the end for further clarification is. I am trying to achieve something like this IF AND ONLY IF the test   `test="contains($txt,'[&lt;a')">` is true.

    <font name='Verdana' size='14pt'>
     <a href="www.google.com">Google</a>
    </font>

If the test `test="contains($txt,'[&lt;a')">` is FALSE, then I just want the `<font name = 'Verdana' size='14pt'>`to surround the text() contents of the run element.

Comment: @spikycactus As I said, this has nothing to do with your original question. Start a new one.

Comment: Sorry, didn't notice your comment. I will create a new post now. Cheers